# How to propagate a user to github workflows triggered by a github bot

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

We have a release process which requires a bit more logic than github workflows allow. For this reason, we have written a github bot which receives events and triggers workflows based on those events, after some logic. The bot-triggered workflows will always originate from a user performing some sort of operation (like merging a PR, pushing code, editing/publishing a release etc.)

On workflows triggered by this bot, the "actor" or "assignee" is the github bot user, meaning that any notifications which arise from the workflow run are not received by anybody. Is there a way to instruct github to change the "assignee" of workflow runs triggered by the bot so that the original user receives notifications?

Comment: From the documentation, it seems you won't be able to do what you want once the workflow run has been triggered, so the solution might be to trigger the workflow differently. How does your github bot trigger the workflows? I imagine it might be using a PAT through a http request to the Github API or something similar. If so, instead of doing the request with your github bot PAT, you could do it by using the user PAT (persisting it somehow through your process).

Comment: It would be fine to trigger the workflow with the original user - there is no need for it to be updated during the workflow. At the moment, the API is authenticated using the github bot token. Using a different token would work if we would like all workflows to be performed against a single user. This doesn't scale to many users in an organisation very well.

Comment: What do you mean by: _Using a different token would work if we would like all workflows to be performed against a single user_? Don't you want the workflows to be triggered by the original user (which triggered your github bot)?

Comment: That's correct, so I'm just pointing out that using a user's token to ensure the workflow is run as that user requires up-front configuration of that user's token and then some logic to match the token with the user information as received in the original event. Which is fine if there is 1 user by which all the workflows are triggered, but doesn't scale to a team of users.

Comment: Would it be an option to extract the users token automatically before sending the event with it to the github bot ?

Comment: How so? The event is generated by GitHub when the user performs an action like merging a PR or editing a release (as per the question).

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to have a workflow generating / extracting the user PAT when performing those operations on Github, which would then call the Github bot? A Github App may do it as well (it may even be easier to extract the token that way).

Comment: Generating user's tokens on the fly is not something we'd like to do (as it creates pretty noisy notifications, and requires increased security responsibility) and if we were to go down this route, generating them up-front probably requires less effort. Again, I'm not aware of "extracting" tokens from anywhere.

Comment: I'm not aware of other workaround. Having a customized solution will involve being able to extract the datas you need to perform other operations, such as notifications or user impersonation. However, it's as you said, it comes with security issues. I don't believe you will be able to achieve what you want without following that path.